# jquery-cycle2 carousel with multiple slides responsive and centered. Possible?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, carousel, jquery-cycle2

Is it possible to have "cycle2" to slide multiple items in a carousel centered in the fluid/responsive slideshow?

[image: three slides]

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem in your post and don't just include a link. Links rot, and your post should stand alone from any other resource; this question will lose any value to future visitors if link is blocked or goes away in the future!

Comment: have you read my question?